# Converting Native C# Calls to Java (with JNA)

Tags: c#, java, jna

I am new here. As well, I need some help with converting some C# code to Java using JNA to call native Windows functions.

First and foremost, this is the code I am trying to convert:
http://pastebin.com/0b5zMvBg

So far, I have written the JNA interfaces to represent the Kernel32 and NtDll library. Within the Kernel32 library, I have also defined the structures that I need to use.

**Kernel32.java**
http://pastebin.com/93xTvD0T

**NtDll.java**
http://pastebin.com/giup88Tk

After I have defined the library and structures I moved on to writing the non-native functions. The problem is, I don't understand all of the C# syntax. I do, however, understand all of the Java features that are in C#.

Here is what I have written so far; note that I have commented what I don't understand as well as if I'm questionable about my conversion. Most of the problems repeat, meaning that if you supply me with even one conversion I will probably be able to figure out how to do the rest. Thanks in prior for any help! :-)

http://pastebin.com/jfuzq0cj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you're not even doing anything specific to C#, but basic C pointer arithmetic.

The easiest way to walk around a block of data and perform conversions between data types is to use `com.sun.jna.Memory` rather than `byte[]`.  You can use `Pointer.share(long offset)` to perform pointer arithmetic (the result is the original pointer offset by the requested amount).  You can read and write the native memory using various `Pointer.write()` or `Pointer.readXXX()` variants.

You can initialize Java-side `Structure` objects using a `Pointer` as the base address, just remember to explicitly call `Structure.read()` to sync native memory to Java.

A few examples, from your pasty:

```
Memory data = ...;
// mzH = *(MZHeader*) dPtr;
MZHeader mzH = new MZHeader(data);
mzH.read(); // or put this in the MZHeader(Pointer) ctor
// peH = *(PE_Header*)&dPtr[mzH.offsetToPE];
PE_Header peH = new PE_Header(data.share(mzH.offsetToPE));
peH.read(); // or put this in the PE_Header(Pointer) ctor
// peXH = *(PE_ExtHeader*)&dPtr[mzH.offsetToPE + sizeof(PE_Header)];
PE_ExtHeader peXH = new PE_ExtHeader(data.share(mzH.offsetToPE + peH.size()));
peXH.read(); // or put this in the PE_ExtHeader(Pointer) actor
```

I think you can get the idea from there...

**EDIT**

```
Pointer p = new Memory();
byte[] data = ...;
// Copy into Memory from data
p.write(0, data, 0, data.length);
// Copy out of Memory into data
p.read(0, data, 0, data.length);
```

Comment: How can I construct a _Memory_ object from an array of bytes?

Comment: Also, what is the equivalent of using Marshal's Copy? _Marshal.Copy(peBytes, (int)secHdrs[i].pointerToRawData, (IntPtr)ptr, copySize);_

Comment: There's no direct native to native memory copy, but you can easily map `memcpy` or similar C library function to do so.

Answer (score 1):

So your Kine.Run() looks like the main entry point of this code. And what it does is take the given byte array, fork the current process, then overwrite the current process memory with the byte array and start executing it. If you implemented this, you would run the byte array as a child process.

Now, assuming that the byte array comes from some file in the file system (or can be written there), you can replace ALL this code with the following line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filename);
```

Assuming that the filename is the file that contains the byte array.  No knowledge of the PE header or windows internals is necessary. If the byte array comes from some where you cannot store locally, then you won't be able to run it anyway.

Comment: The JVM is not designed to allow you to execute arbitrary machine code. I don't think this can be done the way you want it done. Do you know what the code that you will be executing is doing? Can you make interpret the code, or load it as classes?

Answer (score -1):

Not to be pedantic, but don't do that. You are trying to run a C# program in a JVM? It would be simpler and faster to write a layer that abstracts out the OS specific parts of the application. There are several things you can do in C# that will not work in a JVM. Such as load DLLs and then call methods in them. Or get the messages from the windows message loop.

Now, I will agree that there are some things you may want to do that can only be done from a native library. Like interact with other windows. But you are re-implementing the CLR in Java.  That's a HUGE amount of work, and some parts will NEVER WORK.

Just don't do it. (Insert nike swoosh here)

Comment: Um, what are you talking about? I am rewriting a C# program to Java. The C# uses native calls and I am using JNA to do native calls in Java. The issue isn't loading the DLLs and calling methods but translating the implementation C# code to Java. I am not re-implementing the CLR in Java, I have no idea where you got this from. Did you even look at the code I'm trying to translate?

Comment: If you were rewriting the c# program, you wouldn't need the JNA calls. You would rewrite these c# calls with java equivalents. You should be changing the application code, not writing the CLR equivalent functions. Why does your application need to write into other processes' memory spaces?

Comment: But I need the JNA calls because they are the meat of the application. The application's job is to execute an array of bytes (which makes up an executable) without having the executable hit the hard drive. Please view the code I am having trouble with, it shows in the comments the troubles I am having because I do not know the Java equivalents. The native calls are _not_ my issue.

Comment: The code you have pasted does not show what the application does. It only shows that you are trying to create processes. I think you are tackling this problem at too low a level. If you are writing a scripting environment, then you need to actually implement the script primitives in java. java.nio.ByteBuffer can be used to read the array of bytes (and shorts, ints, longs, floats, and doubles!) and then each opcode can then be processed.